# Customize desktop icon grid location and dimensions on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, desktop-environments, customization, desktop-icons

i'm gonna preface this by saying that i'm a new linux user, i joined circa 2 months ago, as such, i don't know too much about linux and its distros, but i've already got some tools like dconf and gconf-editor, gnome-tweaks, etc.

what i want to do is move the desktop icons so that they don't get overlayed by the taskbar.

in the following examples i represent the icon grid as a series of red squares.

[see examples](https://imgur.com/a/4FZqXYm)

i did google what to do, but the only things i could find were about icon spacing, scaling, taskbar icons, **tl;dr i couldn't find anything fitting to what i want to do.**

maybe it's not even possible to do that, but i have no idea.

also, on a sidenote that's unrelated to this: why is some basic funtionality, such as desktop icons **not** enabled by default?

Comment: Just a remark: this site is a Q&A site, so one single question per post. With respect to you second question, desktop icons *are* enabled by default in standard Ubuntu.

Comment: huh, weird, i had to enable it in both 19.10 and 20.04.